# Need to sort excel multiColumns list box

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, listbox

can someone help me with sorting listbox by dates? 
I know that there is not built in sorting algorithm for listboxes.
It's a list with 12 columns and the 10th is a date.
I tried bubble sort (with two nested for statements), but i cant get entire row in temporary variable so i can swap it.
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use disconnected recordsets for sorting and filtering.

```
Sub Randomise
    Randomize 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
     'Define table
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 
            .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
             'Add data
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            .AddNew
            .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
              'tell it to sort
        .Sort = "RandomNumber"
              'Write it back out
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```